# Hooks setState always one step behind

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I used the useState hook. Was supposed to trigger a set state method (in hooks) everytime the value of a dropdown button changes but the set state always happen one step behind. I've seen solutions with the traditional setState methods of class based components, but how do i fix this using hooks `useState`?

```
<Dropdown
  placeholder='Select College'
  search
  fluid
  selection
  options={collegeSelection}
  onChange={selectCollegeHandler}
/>
```

Method:

```
const selectedCollegeHandler = (event, data) => {
  setSelectedCollege(data.value);
}
```

State:

```
const [selectedCollegeState, setSelectedCollege] = useState(' ');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the set state always happen one step behind"? `setSelectedCollege` is asynchronous just like `setState` in a class component, so you won't get an updated value straight away.

Comment: So how do i fix it? i need to get an updated value as soon as onChange triggers.

Comment: how did you put the variables search, fluid and selection without any assignment, are these states ?

Answer (score 8):

For completion it's worth mentioning that `useEffect` is designed to help with this asynchrony. In fact, according to the Hooks docs, [the hooks solution is to use the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), (which essentially *is* implementing a callback with useState).

```
const CollegeForm = () => {
const [college, setCollege] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(college); // add whatever functions use new `college` value here.
}, [college]);

return (
<form onChange={e => setCollege(e.target.value)} />
    )
};
```

This (side) Effect is called when (and only when) Bob chooses a new college in your form. Whatever logic is based on his every indecisive prevarication over `college` choice can go inside this useEffect callback. (You can also use Effect without the dependency array, `[college]`, which will cause these (side) effects every time any state changes).

To explain relative to the class based components: with the "traditional" setState methods we could just add a callback as a second argument to `setState` so the new state was used immediately:

```
this.setState({ college: data.value }, () => console.log(new value));
```

The callback prevents it being queued in what the React docs call a [pending state transition](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). But we can no longer do this because *hooks do not take callbacks*.

As cbdeveloper says, sometimes passing a function to setState is appropriate, for example:

```
[isOnline, toggleIsOnline] = useState(false);
```

```
<Button onClick={() => toggleIsOnline(prevState => !prevState)} />
```

But this isn't always appropriate, especially if you're not actually using the `prevState`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Using the functional form of `setState()` you can "trick" React into thinking that your new state depends on your last state, so it does the update right away. This has helped me on a number of ocasions. See if that helps you too.

```
method:
  const selectedCollegeHandler = (event, data) => {
    setSelectedCollege((prevState) => {
      return data.value
    });
  }
```

> **Functional updates**
>
> If the new state is computed using the previous
>   state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive
>   the previous value, and return an updated value. Here’s an example of
>   a counter component that uses both forms of setState:

[Source: Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

Comment: Can you provide Sandbox with minimal functionality example?

Answer (score 2):

Try async function. It solved the same issue for me.

```
const selectedCollegeHandler = async(event, data) => {
     await setSelectedCollege(data.value);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).