# React : parent props changes, but children (with map) update one step behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I pass a prop **data** which contain a field **worktypeData** witch has a field that changes.
When I console log I can see **data** updated, but the console log in the map is one step behind late.

I tried with a useEffect that set a new state with **data **in the dependencies, but same result.
Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55600870/hooks-setstate-always-one-step-behind) too, but same result.

```
// this is the type of the field in OfficeOccupancyCardData that I want to update
interface WorkTypeData {
    selected: WorkType;
    onClick: (worktype: WorkType) => void;
    buttonLink: string;
}


interface DashboardNextDaysProps {
    data: OfficeOccupancyCardData[];
}

const DashboardNextDays: React.FunctionComponent<DashboardNextDaysProps> = ({ data }) => {
    // console log here will show data with the new value

    return (
        <HorizontalGridSlide className="DashboardNextDays" colSize={286} gap={16} pageSlide>
            {data.length > 0 &&
                data.map((day, i) => {
                    // console log here will show data with the value not updated
                    return <OfficeOccupancyCard key={generateKey(i)} data={day} />;
                })}
        </HorizontalGridSlide>
    );
};
```

EDIT: I found a solution, if someone can explain to me why this works.
In the parent of **DashboardNextDays** I have a useEffect to set the new data :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        setNextDaysData((prev) => {
            const newNextDaysData = prev;
            if (newNextDaysData && nextDayWorktypeSelected)
                newNextDaysData[nextDayWorktypeSelected.dayIndex] = {
                    ...newNextDaysData?.[nextDayWorktypeSelected.dayIndex],
                    worktypeData: {
                        ...newNextDaysData?.[nextDayWorktypeSelected.dayIndex].worktypeData,
                        selected: nextDayWorktypeSelected.worktype,
                    },
                };

            return newNextDaysData ? newNextDaysData : [];
        });
    }, [nextDayWorktypeSelected]);
```

And I just changed

```
return newNextDaysData ? newNextDaysData : [];
to
return newNextDaysData ? [...newNextDaysData] : [];
```

Comment: Is there any additional code that's relevant here? I can see no reason why the value of `data` would be different in the map than the value above.

Answer (score 2):

To see the state changes immediately, you need to use useEffect and add newData in the dependency change.

Answer (score 0):

Since setState is asynchronous you can not check state updates in console.log synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

**useEffect** is the hook that manages side-effects in functional components:

`useEffect(callback, dependencies)`. The `callback` argument is a function to put the `side-effect` logic in place. `Dependencies` is a list of your side effect's dependencies, whether they are props or state values.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {

  const [state, setState] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Side-effect uses `prop` and `state`
  }, [prop, state]);
  return <div>....</div>;
}
```